# Comment en est-on venu à « aspirer » le H sur une expiration ?

Tags: sens, terminologie, phonétique

Bien que je ne fume pas, le H de [H]aschich me trouble étrangement : pour l’un l’air sort de la bouche, pour l’autre il y pénètre … deux actions contraires utilisent le même verbe.

De tout temps *aspirer* a eu le sens premier donné par un exemple extrait du site stella.atilf.fr, avec la notion d’attraction vers soi ou par une force centripète :

> Je respire, j’aspire la nuit, la nuit entre en moi par je ne sais quelle inconcevable, quelle inimaginable brèche de l’âme. Je suis moi-même nuit.

Plus loin dans la page :

> MUS., PHONÉT. "Prononcer plus ou moins fortement de la gorge" (Ac. 1835-1932); altérer (un son ou une articulation)

Encore plus troublant, puisque l’on parle de musique : un chanteur qui aspire (l’air, autant vital pour lui que nécessaire à son art) est muet, pour prononcer plus ou moins fortement de la gorge il faut *expirer* ou *refouler* (deux contraires d’*aspirer* cité par le petit Robert) plus ou moins d’air.

À la limite le H *altéré* (donné comme synonyme) serait compréhensible, car il existe des altérations en musique.

Alors,

— Comment s’appelle le H d’effroi ou de surprise qui frotte la gorge quand l’air y rentre brusquement ?

— Le H *aspiré* n’est-il jamais aspiré vers les poumons ?

— Est-ce une conjonction de concepts hétéroclites, une collision illusoire d’apparences ou une quelconque distorsion du langage inaccessible au sens commun ?

— Doit-on se contenter après la réforme de l’orthographe d’un « C’est comme ça », parce que l’Académie a entériné un usage obsolète ?

— Les grands intellectuels de l’Éducation nationale qui ont défrayé la chronique avec leurs définitions parfois ubuesques ne se sont-ils jamais raclé la gorge pour remettre en cause ce H muet qui altère la lettre qui le suit ?

---

***ÉDIT final***

Bien que  [jlliagre](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/31821/848) ait répondu parfaitement, la musique des mots réveillait mon interrogation initiale par moment … jusqu’à ce que je rattache le "*h **aspiré***" à "***aspérité*** du h à expirer (du fond de la gorge)" …  passage du concept d’*altération* à la l’expérience d’une *sensation*.

---

*Un an après … **Sérendipité** !*

Pour *[le sanskrit](http://sanskrit.claude-marillier.net/phonation.html)*

> le H ("aspirée pure") **est soufflé**, plus qu'aspiré (comme *house* en anglais).

Comme quoi, il est nécessaire de remonter à la source ultime pour trouver *a* en première lettre et *ha* (prononcé *soufflé* avec une micro pause ensuite) en quarante-neuvième et dernière position !

Comment: Hmmm... s'agit-il là  d'une profession de foi ? d'une livraison gratuite de sarcasmes variés ou d'un questionnement sincère ?

Comment: @aCOSwt — D’une pierre d’achoppement, de cailloux dans mes chaussures francophones que je n’arrive pas à retirer quelle que soit la façon de m’y prendre. Ce ne sont pas des sarcasmes ni des critiques, seulement une expression libre, de cette liberté amusée qui demande des comptes aux autorités linguistiques ou philologiques en se demandant parfois s’il y a des hommes ou des robots pour en tirer les ficelles des réponses … la réponse révèle le regard qui a lu. Les deux premières peuvent intéresser les linguistes mais j’espère que les philologues s’intéresseront aux dernières, pas les censeurs.

Comment: Alors je ne comprends pas ton interrogation. Tu dis toi-même (et à juste titre) que quand le chanteur aspire l'air il est muet. C'est très exactement ce qu'est le *H aspiré* : muet! Il n'est que dans les langues germaniques que le H à l'initiale s'entend. Il est d'ailleurs dit *expiré*. On rencontre ce H expiré dans de rares cas en français comme dans les interjections *Ho! Holà!* Il peut être aussi laissé à la liberté d'interprétation du locuteur comme dans *hideux* s'il souhaite cracher en même temps sur le truc deg ;)

Comment: @aCOSwt — Affinons : pourquoi donc n’est-il pas appelé H *muet* ? — Pourquoi les langues du Nord collent à la réalité en interrogeant l’action du souffle en le nommant logiquement H *expiré* ? — Une interrogation : dans les interjections *Ho! Holà!* le H n’est-il pas défini malgré tout comme *aspiré* bien que physiquement expiré ? — Certes, on ne dit pas des-z-haricots mais si le H *muet* est *aspiré*, ne devrait-on pas sur une légère inspiration prononcer le *ha* et reprendre l’expiration pour finir le *ricot* ? — *Ha* inspiré ou expiré, sur scène le résultat n’est pas le même, le H décide !

Comment: Tu dis : *Ha inspiré ou expiré, résultat n'est pas le même* et... tu as raison. Aussi tu noteras que deux graphies existent (in dico AF) pour les différencier : *HA!* et *AH!* de même pour *HO!* et *OH!* Après le jeu de scène, c'est le jeu de scène... sur scène il est beaucoup de mots qui contiennent 3 ou 4 R aussi... alors... ;)

Comment: @aCOSwt — Intéressant, mais ce H *ante* ou  *post* posé est-il définit par les autorités comme *muet, aspiré* ou *expiré* ou systématiquement *aspiré* ? — Quant au R il est plus ou moins roulé, mais cela ne remet pas en cause la respiration.

Comment: À ma connaissance aucune *autorité* n'a jamais réglementé la prononciation de quoi que ce soit. Dans la version draft de la dernière édition du Dictionnaire de l'Académie, il existait une notation (apostrophe) à valeur indicative en cas de H aspiré à l'initiale. Cette indication a disparu du livrable.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/83848/discussion-between-cl-r-and-acoswt).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

La contradiction entre ce qualificatif et la prononciation du *h* n'est pas à rechercher du côté de l'Éducation nationale ou de l'Académie, l'utilisation d'aspirer étant largement antérieure aux dites institutions, et probablement non plus du côté d'une prononciation obsolète hypothétique.

Il faut remonter au latin pour trouver l'origine de ce H *aspiré*. Quintilien écrivait au premier siècle après J.C. dans l'Institution oratoire, à propos de la lettre H:

> *Parcissime ea veteres usi etiam in vocalibus, quum aedos ircosque dicebant. Diu deinde servatum, ne consônantibus **aspiraretur**, ut in Graccis et triumpis.*

Dans d'autres éditions du même texte, le temps utilisé est ***adspirarent***.

Ce qui peut se traduire par :

> Les anciens l'utilisaient très sobrement, même devant les voyelles ; car ils disaient "*aedos* et *ircos*" ensuite, longtemps on ne l'**aspira** pas avec les consonnes, et l'on disait *Graccis* et *triumpis* (au lieu de *Gracchis* et *triumphis*).

La prononciation ou non du *h* n'est donc ni une spécificité française, ni une question récente.

On peut avancer quelques hypothèses qui pourraient expliquer pourquoi *aspirer* a été choisi.

En latin, le verbe *a[d]spirare* peut signifier aussi bien aspirer, inspirer que souffler, respirer. Les dictionnaires citent cependant Quintilien comme exemple du sens *aspirer*. Toutefois, ce qui caractérise le *h*, ce n'est pas le fait que l'on expire de l'air en le prononçant, puisque c'est le cas habituel de tous les phonèmes, mais plutôt qu'on interrompt brièvement cette expiration quand on prononce le *h*, ce qu'on appelle le « coup de glotte ». Cet arrêt de l'expiration a peut-être été assimilé à une inspiration.

D'autre part, en grec archaïque, un *h* en début de mot pouvait être représenté par un h coupé en deux, hêta (Ͱ), qui a évolué dans un signe appelé « esprit rude », une espèce d'apostrophe placée sur la première voyelle du mot (ou deuxième si diphtongue). L'esprit rude était appelé *δασὺ πνεῦμα* (*dasù pneûma*, littéralement : « respiration rude ») en grec. Sa traduction latine était *spiritus asper* (respiration âpre). Peut-être que la proximité phonétique entre [a]spir- (respirer) et asper (âpre, rude) a favorisé l'utilisation du préfixe *a[d]-* devant *spirare* sans qu'il soit donc question d'une aspiration mais seulement d'une respiration.

Le TLFi donne d'ailleurs une définition d'aspirer où il n'est nullement question d'inspiration mais de prononciation gutturale, ce qui correspond d'ailleurs plus à *asper* (âpre, rude) qu'à une respiration :

> c) MUS., PHONÉT., Prononcer plus ou moins fortement de la gorge (Ac. 1835-1932); altérer (un son ou une articulation) :
>   6. Il faut supprimer : toutes les lettres qui ne se prononcent pas; toutes celles qui aspirent inutilement la consonne qu'elles précèdent (...). Les consonnes aspirantes seraient plus difficiles à éliminer. Cependant phtisie est inadmissible et ftisie ne l'est guère moins; il faudrait ici se guider sur l'analogie, sur l'italien, sur l'ancienne langue, et dire tisie. Remplacer ph par f : la réforme est faite pour fantôme, fantaisie; elle s'appliquera à tous les mots analogues avec la même facilité. Gourmont, Esthétique de la lang. fr., 1899, p. 64.

Comment: Voilà la réponse attendue, parfaitement documentée et rédigée, elle met fin à mes interrogations et recherches erratiques et m’éclaire sur les source de notre langue indo-européennes, le sanskrit, où la translittération du devanagari utilise ce H onze fois pour ses lettres *ḥ — kh — gh — ch — jh — ṭh — th — dh — ph — bh — h*